# Cannot Uncheck Preserve Aspect Ratio of text box in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, text, dynamic-text

I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I'm have dynamic text box I'm trying to add to the buttom of my legend. The text is about 350 characters so need to resize the text box to fit into my legend. But, the "Preserve Aspect Ratio checkbox is grayed-out.

Tried to look in ESRI help with no luck and even found a thread on a forum with the same question, but the answer did not help.

How do I make my text box size editable?

[image]

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with a legend on a data driven page...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the " thread on a forum with the same question", please?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cant chnage the aspect ratio for text if you add it from Insert menu. However, you can get text with this function by using the **rectangular text box** **on the** **Draw toolbar**. You can find it on the dropdown next to **A**.
Although it would not be a dynamic text but should do the job.

Comment: The only difference between static and dynamic text is the contents (which has tags for dynamic) so how the text box is created is certainly worth looking at.  Creating a rectangular text box may be the answer, so perhaps you can test it and improve this one.